# Best way to develop Excel functions on linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel

I have a client for whom I need to write functions for an Excel workbook. I am running on Manjaro.

Is there any alternative to purchasing Excel (£150) and running on say Crossover/Wine?

Comment: Use LibreOffice

Comment: To write excel functions?

Comment: You are using Linux, so it is better to use LibreOffice Calc instead of Excel. If you really want to develop Excel functions, install a VM with Windows.

Comment: My client uses M$ Excel - no option - So LibreOffice is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wine and PlayOnLinux to install Microsoft Excel on Linux. For details, please refer to this link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-microsoft-excel-linux/